# Declaring parameters on function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

I'm trying to understand parameter implementation on functions and I want to ask a question in an example.

```
def learningFunction(*entry,fileName=None):

    if fileName is not None:

        entry = open(fileName,'r').read() 

    else:

        pass
```

I am trying to do is the following;

- When there will be fileName as an input for a parameter, function should not use entry parameter (For example: `learningFunction(fileName="sample.txt")`)
- Also, there can be just entry variable as an input (For example: `learningFunction("stackoverflow")`)

It should be working for both of these examples, but not at the same time such as; (`learningFunction("stackoverflow",fileName="sample.txt")`)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean function, not method, in your example. Despite that, could you clarify the following *"Also, there can be just entry variable as an input"*.

Comment: You're right, it should have been a **function** not a method and I think I clarify it a little bit more.

Comment: For now, it works actually. @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use named parameters for both entry and filename.
Then your code could look like this

```
def learningFunction(entry=None, filename=None):
    assert not entry!= None and filename!= None, "only one param please"
    ...
```

But you can use your setup, too.
The `*entry` will accept any number of parameters and store them as a tuple.
An empty tuple evaluates to False.

You could use code like this:

```
def learningFunction(*entry, filename=None):
    if entry:
        ...
    else:
```

Here you could use asserts to ensure just a single parameter, too.

```
if entry:
    assert filename == None, "just one param please"
else:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible. You can't have a function defined with two arguments (one grabbing all positionals) and then have it not work for the case where you specify these, that is:

```
learningFunction("stackoverflow",fileName="sample.txt")
```

will be correct.

You *can* add logic *inside* the function body to forbid this, of course. You can't have Python throw an error when invoking it because that is perfectly legal.

No matter what combination of arguments you define, you won't be able to get this, if you need two arguments for your function, the case of two arguments being passed is always acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As you use Python3, you can make use of the `inspect` module to externalize the parameter validation in an annotation function. For example this one will ensure that only one of the parameter of the called function has been populated:

```
def singleparam(func):
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # controls that only one parameter has been populated
        if len(sig.bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments) != 1:
            raise TypeError("Both positional and keyword parameters")
        return func(*args, **kwargs) # call original function
    wrapper.__signature__ = sig      # keeps original signature
    return wrapper
```

You can they define your function:

```
@singleparam
def learningFunction(*entry,fileName=None):
    ...
```

You will get an exception if you call it as `learningFunction("stackoverflow",fileName="sample.txt")`